# How can I instruct VS Code to go to definition of curried function, not currying function

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an API client that declares a number of methods for fetching the data.

In these functions I need to handle refreshing the access token when it expires.

To do this I've created a currying function which handles the token refresh, it looks like this:

```
const refreshTokenAsNeeded = <Data extends StravaTokenData, Result>(
  fn: (data: Data) => Promise<Result>
) => {
  return async (data: Data): Promise<Result> => {
    const { refreshToken, accessToken, expiresAt } = data;

    if (data.expiresAt < unixTime()) {
      logger.info("Token expired, fetching new one");
      const {
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        access_token: accessToken,
        expires_at: expiresAt,
      } = await getNewRefreshToken(data.refreshToken);

      await updateRefreshToken(data.refreshToken, {
        refreshToken,
        accessToken,
        expiresAt,
      });
      logger.info("Token saved");
    }
    return fn({
      ...data,
      refreshToken,
      accessToken,
      expiresAt,
    });
  };
};


export const getActivities = refreshTokenAsNeeded<
  StravaTokenData,
  StravaActivity[]
>(async ({ expiresAt, refreshToken, accessToken }) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get<StravaActivity[]>(
    `${stravaApiBaseUrl}/athlete/activities`,
    {
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    }
  );
  return data;
});
```

An unfortunate side-effect of this is that VSCode will go to the definition of `refreshTokenAsNeeded` when I Cmd+Click `getActivities`,

`const activities = await getActivities(user);`

Is there any way to instruct VS Code not to do this, perhaps with a different type annotation?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre]? (emphasis on "minimal" and "example")